# Google API KEY problema

Tags: android, android-studio, api, google-maps, google-api

Tengo una API KEY valida. Sin embargo, al momento de poner restricción a la API, pues Google sugiere insistentemente que tenga restricciones de uso, coloco la clave SHA-1 y el nombre del paquete de mi app para que solo mi app pueda usar esta API KEY.

Resulta que al instalar la app en un celular desde el pc, todo funciona bien. Pero al descargar la app desde la Play Store, el mapa no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si elimino la restricción, el mapa funciona perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

> Resulta que al instalar la app en un celular desde el pc, todo
> funciona bien. Pero al descargar la app desde la Play Store, el mapa
> no funciona.

Registraste el `SHA1` del Keystore de desarrollo (debug.keystore), debes obtener y registrar el `SHA1` del Keystore con el que firmas tu app para Google Play Store.

> Si elimino la restricción, el mapa funciona perfectamente.

Aquí lo que sucede es que no especificas ninguna restricción por lo tanto va a funcionar pero lo correcto es que el uso de tu API sea restringida.

---

Para obtener el SHA1 de tu Keystore usa:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore nombre.keystore
```

Al obtener el `SHA1` configuralo para el mismo paquete de tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]